# How do I solder to a soldered overlay board?

Tags: breadboard, prototyping, protoboard

I have several rather important circuits on breadboards that I want to move to [solder overlay boards](http://www.newark.com/twin-industries/8300sb1-lf/prototyping-board-fr-4-epoxy-6/dp/53Y2059). Unfortunately, my project involves a lot of wires that need to plug into this board - and I cannot move the board or get access to the underside with all the wires in place.

Accordingly, I want to be able to solder wires into holes from the top of the solder overlay board. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Put in the wire and solder it to a pad?

Comment: @PlasmaHH You typically solder to the back of the board with this style of board. If that's really how you do it, then post that. Of course, evidence from experience would be nice.

Comment: If your boards are double-sided - they have solderable pads on both sides - then they *should* also be through-hole-plated - meaning that it doesn't matter which side you do the soldering on as it will be connected on both sides.

Comment: @dpdt: It is a prototyping board, you solder it in any way you want. Often I use enamelled wire with a coating that vaporizes when you apply solder, that makes things easier here

Comment: Use twisted pair AWG30 magnet wire for critical logic or high impedance analog or  ribbon wire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That board looks to have fully plated thru holes with pads on both sides.  That means the top side isn't more special electrically than the bottom.  You can just as well solder wires from the top as from the bottom.

Also, if you solder parts incrementally as you install them, then only one part at a time has to be held in place when you flip the board over.  Parts with bendable leads, like thru-hole resistors, stay in place after you bend the leads a little bit.  After you solder, you clip off the excess lead anyway, to the bent lead won't short against anything.

Comment: I know it's a little early to accept, but this answer has all the info I need and I probably won't be on EE.SE for a while, so I don't want to forget.